# Using Tap Gestures on images within listview

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using Prism in my Xamarin forms app, I have a `ListView` where each Listitem has 2 images, an edit image and delete image.

I have used`TapGesturesRecognizers` on these 2 images, and binded _`DelegateCommands` for these `TapGestureRecognizers`. However these DelegateCommands do not get called.

Thanks in advance

This is my XAML code

```
<ListView x:Name="lstAddress" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" >
        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped"
          Command="{Binding ListItemSelectCommand}"  EventArgsParameterPath="Item"/>
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="15" TextColor="#959595">
                        </Label>
                        <Image Source="Edit.png"  HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" IsVisible="{Binding ShowEdit}">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command ="{Binding EditAddressCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <Image Source="Delete.png" ClassId="{Binding ListID}" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" IsVisible="{Binding ShowIcon}">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command ="{Binding DeleteAddressCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

In my ViewModel:

```
public class AddressBookViewModel : BindableBase
{
    INavigationService  _navigationService;
    public DelegateCommand EditAddressCommand { get;  set; }
    public DelegateCommand DeleteAddressCommand { get;  set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ListModel> ListItems {get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<ListModel>();

    public DelegateCommand<ListModel> ListItemSelectCommand { get;  set; }


    public MyZypListsViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        EditAddressCommand = new DelegateCommand(EditAddress);
        DeleteAddressCommand = new DelegateCommand(DeleteAddress);
        ListItemSelectCommand = new DelegateCommand<ListModel>(ListItemSelected);
    }

    private void EditAddress()
    {
       //Edit listitem  
    }

    private void DeleteAddress()
    {
       //Delete listitem   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each item on your list, your `BindingContext` is not the same as the `ListView`'s `BindingContext`. Locally your `BindingContext` is the item itself, this is why you can obtain the 'Description' property, for example. `Xamarin` is searching for an `ICommand` called `EditAddressCommand` in your item, not in your view model.

You can make a Cross Binding reference if you want... Just replace your commands at item template to this way:

```
Command ="{Binding BindingContext.EditAddressCommand, Source={x:Reference lstAddress}"
```

It may work.